Integration or numerical integration over one variable out of many variables
I have a function defined as
AFB = (6*I6parSMM)/(2*(3*I1cparSMM + 6*I1sparSMM - I2cparSMM - 2*I2sparSMM));

where the I'parSMM's are functions of other variables s, C7priSM, C7NP, C7priNP, C9NP, C9priNP, C10NP, C10priNP, BLdb, errC9NP, errC9priNP, errC10NP and more.
I fix the values of some of the variables but keep some as they are as
AFBSMC = AFB /. {BLdb -> 0, \[Phi] -> 0, errC9NP -> 0, 
errC9priNP -> 0, errC10NP -> 0, errC10priNP -> 0, errA00 -> 0, 
errA01 -> 0, errA02 -> 0, errA10 -> 0, errA11 -> 0, errA12 -> 0, 
errA120 -> 0, errA121 -> 0, errA122 -> 0, errV00 -> 0, 
errV01 -> 0, errV02 -> 0, errT10 -> 0, errT11 -> 0, errT12 -> 0, 
errT20 -> 0, errT21 -> 0, errT22 -> 0, errT230 -> 0, errT231 -> 0,
 errT232 -> 0, mR -> 5.37};

Now AFBSMC is function of s, C7priSM, C7NP, C7priNP, C9NP, C9priNP, C10NP and C10priNP.
I want to integrate/numerically integrate over s but pass other variables to output. I tried things like
integratedAFBNN[C7priSM_, C7NP_, C7priNP_, C9NP_, C9priNP_, C10NP_,C10priNP_] :=NIntegrate[AFBSMC[s, C7priSM, C7NP, C7priNP, C9NP, C9priNP, C10NP,C10priNP], {s, 1, 8}];

integratedAFBNN[C7priSM_, C7NP_, C7priNP_, C9NP_, C9priNP_, C10NP_, C10priNP_] := NIntegrate[Evaluate[AFBSMC[s, C7priSM, C7NP, C7priNP, C9NP, C9priNP, C10NP, C10priNP]], {s, 1, 8}]

integratedAFBNN[C7priSM_, C7NP_, C7priNP_, C9NP_, C9priNP_, C10NP_, C10priNP_] := Integrate[ AFBSMC[s, C7priSM, C7NP, C7priNP, C9NP, C9priNP, C10NP, C10priNP], {s, 1, 8}]

but nothing seems to work. How should I perform the integration? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

If you edit your post to show us the actual definitions of  your "I'parSMM's" then it may be possible for someone to spot the problem and suggest a fix. You will need to use Integrate because NIntegrate will not accept expressions containing symbolic input.

A concrete example: f[x_, y_] := Exp[y] Sin[x]; Integrate[f[x, y], {x, 0, Pi}] works for me. So does NIntegrate[f[x, 1.5], {x, 0, Pi}]. These seem the same as yours. OTOH, Integrate[f[x^3 + x, y], {x, 0, Pi}] does not yield an answer; not every integral can done symbolically. BTW, Replace[NIntegrate`GaussKronrodRuleData[15, MachinePrecision], {xvals_, weights_,  errweights_} :> {weights, errweights}.(f[#, y]& /@ Rescale[xvals, {0, 1}, {a, b}])*(b - a)] yields an estimate of the x integral from a to b and an estimate of the error (as a functions of y). No refinement, though.

@Bill The expressions for IpasSMM's are really very long to show here.
